# Difference-in-Differences with Aggregated Data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, difference-in-difference, control-group

I have access to aggregated data of a population for a 1,5 year period. I am interested in conducting an events study to check whether the implementation of a certain treatment will affect the behavior of my subjects.

Since i do not have individual level data can i conduct a *Diff in Diff* analysis?

If yes, could I set a certain time period, observe the alterations in the population's values there and use that as my Control Group? Then, I could take the same time period in terms of length after the implementation of the treatment and observe the population's differences there.

In other words can I create a CG and TG from the same population just by varying the time periods?

I apologize for the simplicity of my question but I have not cleared this in my head yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correctly understanding your description of the data then the answer is no.

To use Differences in Differences (DID) you need: 1.) a group that receives treatment and a group that does not; 2.) a time period before treatment and a time period after treatment *for both groups*.

Lets say our outcome is $Y_{g,t}$ with $g$ indexing whether you are the treatment group and $t$ indexing the time period. Thus $Y_{g=1, t=0}$ would denote the outcome for the treated group in the time period before treatment. The estimator is then simply $DID = [Y_{g=1, t=1} - Y_{g=1, t=0}] - [Y_{g=0, t=1} - Y_{g=0, t=0}]$.

In a silly toy description: I want to know if eating an ice-cream makes me gain weight. Since only I will eat the ice cream my wife is the control. I start out weighing 180 ($Y_{g=1, t=0} = 180$), and my wife starts out a slim 400 ($Y_{g=0, t=0} = 400$). After I eat an ice cream, we both weigh ourselves and my wife is now 420 ($Y_{g=0, t=1}=420$) and I am now 210 ($Y_{g=1, t=1}=210$). Thus the DID estimator of the effect is $[210 - 180] - [420-400] = 30-20=10$. The interpretation would thus be that the ice cream caused me to gain 10, and in the counter-factual state of the world in which I did not eat ice-cream I would have weighed a mere 200.

If I understand your description of your data, you have pre- and post-treatment observations, but you do not have some units that are treated and some that are not, thus DID would not be appropriate.

Comment: Wow that was really helpful! Thank you very much for your reply.  If DiD is not possible what other regression model would be possible to use in this kind of data?